# Extracting XML data with Linq in C# difficulty

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So I'm working with reading an xml file to create a dictionary, but I can't figure out how to access the xml fields I want.

Below is the format of the XML I want to read.

```html
<Days>
    <Day Name="Monday">
        <Task Order="1">TestTask</Task>
        <Task Order="2">Test2</Task>
    </Day>
</Days>
```

Below is my code so far. I've tried a lot of variations for finding task and order, such as for task: (string)e, or e.ToString(), or e.Elements("Task").Value.ToString();  And for order e.Attributes("Order").ToString();

```
        string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");           
        var allItems = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        XElement root = XElement.Parse(_orderxml);
        IEnumerable<XElement> address =
            from el in root.Elements("Day")
            where el.Attribute("Name").Value == today
            select el;
        foreach (XElement e in address)
        {
            string task = ???;
            string order = ???;
            allItems.Add(task, (int)order);
        }
```

So far, none of these have given me the right results, and I'm really unsure of what the proper way to get this data is, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second loop to iterate the tasks and extract the values

```
static void Main()
    {
        string _orderxml = @"<Days>    <Day Name=""Wednesday"">        <Task Order=""1"">TestTask</Task>        <Task Order=""2"">Test2</Task>    </Day></Days>";
        string today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");
        var allItems = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        XElement root = XElement.Parse(_orderxml);
        IEnumerable<XElement> address =
            from el in root.Elements("Day")
            where el.Attribute("Name").Value == today
            select el;
        foreach (XElement e in address)
        {
            foreach (XElement t in e.Descendants())
            {
                string task = t.Value.ToString();

                int order = int.Parse(t.Attribute("Order").Value.ToString());
                allItems.Add(task, (int)order);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or you can do it with a Linq query like this

```
var result=root.Descendants("Day").Where(d=>d.Attribute("Name").Value==today).Descendants("Task").Select(x => new {Task=x.Value,Order=x.Attribute("Order") });
```

Or create a dictionary from the anonymous objects

```
var result = root.Descendants("Day").Where(d=>d.Attribute("Name").Value==today).Select(x => new { Task = x.Value.ToString(), Order = x.Attribute("Order") }).ToDictionary(c => c.Task, c => c.Order);
```

Or create a dictionary directly from the linq query

```
var result = root.Descendants("Day").Where(d=>d.Attribute("Name").Value==today).ToDictionary(c => c.Value.ToString(), c => int.Parse(c.Attribute("Order").Value.ToString()));
```